# Is there a risk of breaking a document by opening in word online

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, sharepoint

I use sharepoint in my Company.

Each time I want to view a document, I right click on it and then choose "preview" or "Open in word" (for desktop) instead of directly clicking on it.

I do this because I'm afraid to "break" the document wich has been created first in word for desktop with advanced features that are not supported in Word Online.

Does this risk exist or I'm simply paranoiac ?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing right.

The two versions of Word do have differences as far as formatting is
considered. Therefore a document formatted on the one version may
look different on the other.

This is because some features are lacking in the online version,
or are implemented differently, or some fonts are missing.

It is therefore advised to create and modify the document only on
one version of Word, unless the document uses only basic features.
Note that saving counts as modification.

Here are some cases I have found :

- [MS Word Online messes up the document created on MS Word Desktop App](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-word-online-messes-up-the-document-created-on/6eaa4aba-6630-4473-8f1d-e5db162fb26b)
- [Formatting keeps changing between Desktop/Online & Mac/PC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/formatting-keeps-changing-between-desktoponline/3957795b-5d4c-41d7-89e1-5e29b25105d9)

Answer (score 2):

### Opening in Word Online will not cause damage. Editing may.

Viewing and printing using Word online should cause no problems.
Especially with automatic numbering, editing in the online version has been known to break the numbering.

Comment: since the document is automatically saved, isn't there still a risk that just opening the document in Word Online will cause it to be saved?  And therefore that the document is broken?

Comment: AFAIK, opening and saving does not break. Opening, editing and saving may.

Answer (score 1):

Simple paranoia. There's no damage to be done. If you want to protect yourself, enable track changes to mitigate or change the drop-down from Editing to Viewing

[image]

Comment: Editing in Word's online version is known to break automatic numbering lists. Turning on Track Changes is likely to exacerbate problems.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure if the cause is opening with Word Online or syncing via OneDrive for Business, but I have encountered multiple times that the [`INCLUDEPICTURE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-includepicture-field-a3aac6dc-4e08-4d62-9aac-794279d02de9) field (where the actual image is hosted on a Sharepoint URL) gets replaced by the actual picture instead of remaining a reference to the image.

I've simply stopped using the field instead of not opening with Word Online.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is no risk in opening the same Word document online and locally.